# Is there a method to create a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists like these:

```
a = [12, 23, 45, 56]
b = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And I want to create a dict using `a` and `b` like this:

```
c = {12:0, 23:0, 45:0, 56:0}
```

Is there a easy method to do this?

Comment: You can use `zip` and `dict` together. `dict(zip(a,b))` gives the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
a = [12, 23, 45, 56]
b = [0, 0, 0, 0]
c = dict(zip(a,b))
```

`zip` iterates through your lists in parallel, delivering them in pairs. `dict` accepts a sequence of key/value pairs and uses them to make a dictionary.

If you actually want a dictionary where every value is zero, you don't even need the `b` list. You can just have

```
c = {k:0 for k in a}
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a n item list like [0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Yes, `[0]*4` will give you `[0,0,0,0]`

Comment: @Just_Me yea, list = [0]*n

Answer (score -1):

Just loop through them together:

```
c = {}
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    c[i] = j
```

Or either a direct usage of zip and dict together:

```
keys = ()
values = ()
result = dict(zip(keys, values))
# or
result = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
```

Comment: I think dict(zip(a,b)) is easier

Comment: yep it is :) a simpler solution for beginners :)

Comment: I am sorry, but I am using python for 4 years :D

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a lot of these really shouldn't be recommened aside from `dict(zip(keys, values))`. The loop, and dictionary comprehension for example. Everytime you see something like `result = {k: v for k, v in whatever}` it should be `dict(whatever)`, similarly with list comprehensions, `[x for x in whatever]` should just be `list(whatever)`. Some people will downvote answers / questions that they consider "obvious" duplicates. I think that's harsh but some people do it.